# Count a specific relationship in OWL File using sparql query

Tags: sparql, jena, owl, ontology

I want to count assertions of a specific relationship in OWL file. if following is my whole Ontology:-

```xml
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="file:/C:/myOnt.owl#comfort">
  <SynonymOf rdf:resource="file:/C:/myOnt.owl#impunity"/>
  <SynonymOf rdf:resource="file:/C:/myOnt.owl#sooth"/>
  <SynonymOf rdf:resource="file:/C:/myOnt.owl#ease"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="file:/C:/myOnt.owl#population">
  <SynonymOf rdf:resource="file:/C:/myOnt.owl#habitation"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

then sparql query should give me something like:-

```
       SynonymOf = 4 (i.e 4 assertions for <SynonymOf> relation
```

I intend to run the query on jena fuzeki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward way would be:

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example.com#>
SELECT (count(?o) as ?count)
WHERE {
  ?s :SynonymOf ?o
}
```

However, for the binding to be assigned to specific objects, you might want to consider using `Group By`:

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example.com#>
SELECT ?s (count(?o) as ?count)
WHERE {
  ?s :SynonymOf ?o
}
GROUP BY ?s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (COUNT(?s) as ?SynonymOf)
WHERE {
    GRAPH ?g {?s SynonymOf ?o }
    }
```

Comment: You really don't need `?g`.

Comment: depends on the triplestore you are using. With Stradog you need it unless you are using directly the default graph. Many others triple stores put a copy of every triple in every graph in the default graph, so you really don't need it. I'm not familiar with jena fuzeki but using `?g` is the more conservative hypothesis.

Comment: @ffa If the triples are in the default graph and not in any named graph, though, won't `graph ?g { ... }` exclude them?  The spec says "When querying a collection of graphs, the GRAPH keyword is used to match patterns against named graphs. GRAPH can provide an IRI to select one graph or use a variable which will range over the IRI of all the named graphs in the query's RDF dataset."  So really, you'd need `{graph ?g { ... }} union { ... }`.  But then that might could some things twice if the default is the union of the named graphs (but it's not guaranteed to be).